# Tomcat Custom MBean

Tags: tomcat, jmx

Does anyone know how to deploy a custom MBean to Tomcat?

So far I`ve found this http://www.junlu.com/list/3/8871.html. I copied my jar with my MBean to Tomcat lib directory so the Custom class loader should pick it up. I then followed the instructions but I kept getting the exception below. My MBean does definitely have a public constructor. If I removed the jar from the tomcat lib directory I get the same message which suggests its not picking up my jar or my jar is being loaded after the Apache MBean Modeler is running in Tomcat.

06-Aug-2010 12:14:23 org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.modules.MbeansSource execute
SEVERE: Error creating mbean Bean:type=Bean
javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException: MBean class must have public constructor
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Introspector.testCreation(Introspector.java:127)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.createMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:2
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.createMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.createMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:393)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.modules.MbeansSource.execute(MbeansSource.java:207)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.modules.MbeansSource.load(MbeansSource.java:137)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.readEngineMbeans(StandardEngine.java:517)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.init(StandardEngine.java:321)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:411)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)

Answer (score 1):

In my tests, this message appeared when class name and the name attribute in the mbeans-descriptors.xml file didn't match.

```
<mbeans-descriptors>
<mbean name="<your class name here>"
...
```

It seems tomcat is searching the constructor by the name attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat MBean support is based on [Apache Commons Modeler](http://commons.apache.org/modeler/), which also defines the format of the XML descriptor. See [this thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/users@tomcat.apache.org/msg50110.html) for more pointers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain if this is required in the JMX spec or not, but you must name your interface FooMBean if your implementing class is named Foo. If you do not do this, you will receive an exception upon deployment stating: MBean is not compliant. This is extremely important!!!